# Can a lightning component manipulate DOM outside the component itself? If not, what are my options?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

**Requirement**: My controller code should be able to navigate through the DOM (*of the whole page, not just the wrapping component*), locate elements and add overlay (like tooltips) on identified elements. Since my code is going to run inside my custom lightning component's scope, I guess it cannot gain access to the elements outside the component itself, but I am hoping someone could prove me wrong. ;) Here is an example use-case: the controller code of my component embedded on the Lightning homepage must locate the Home tab in the standard Lightning Navbar and add a tooltip there.

I know this can be done using a browser extension and there are third party apps available for the tool-tip use-case, but I am trying to find if there is a way to implement it using a lightning component. Please let me know if this is possible. If not, what are some alternatives worth exploring?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, Lockerservice was introduced to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to circumvent the Shadow DOM. Even if there *was*, it would only have been a bug that would need to be fixed. You'll need to resort to extensions if you want to have this kind of feature.